conda - InvalidArchivError - [Errno 36] File name too long
I want to install anaconda via conda, but the following error appears
conda install anaconda
Downloading and Extracting Packages:
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

InvalidArchiveError("Error with archive /home/mathias/install/miniconda3/pkgs/arrow-cpp-14.0.2-h374c478_1.conda.  You probably need to delete and re-download or re-create this file.  Message was:\n\nfailed with error: [Errno 36] File name too long: '/home/mathias/install/miniconda3/pkgs/arrow-cpp-14.0.2-h374c478_1/share/gdb/auto-load/croot/arrow-cpp_1707253267958/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placeho'")


I applied <conda clean --all> and restarted the installation process. Same error.
The Linux Mint 22 "Wilma" is newly installed, there is plenty diskspace as well.
Filesystem             1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                    1605464     2112   1603352   1% /run
efivarfs                     246      169        73  70% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
/dev/nvme0n1p2         490617784 41403528 424218776   9% /
tmpfs                    8027308        8   8027300   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                       5120       16      5104   1% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p1            523248    14812    508436   3% /boot/efi
tmpfs                    1605460     3784   1601676   1% /run/user/1000
/home/mathias/.Private 490617784 41403528 424218776   9% /home/mathias

conda info
/home/mathias/install/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda/base/context.py:982: FutureWarning: Adding 'defaults' to the channel list implicitly is deprecated and will be removed in 25.3. 

To remove this warning, please choose a default channel explicitly via 'conda config --add channels <name>', e.g. 'conda config --add channels defaults'.
  deprecated.topic(

     active environment : base
    active env location : /home/mathias/install/miniconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /home/mathias/.condarc
 populated config files : 
          conda version : 24.9.1
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.12.4.final.0
                 solver : libmamba (default)
       virtual packages : __archspec=1=skylake
                          __conda=24.9.1=0
                          __glibc=2.39=0
                          __linux=6.8.0=0
                          __unix=0=0
       base environment : /home/mathias/install/miniconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /home/mathias/install/miniconda3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/mathias/install/miniconda3/pkgs
                          /home/mathias/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/mathias/install/miniconda3/envs
                          /home/mathias/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/24.9.1 requests/2.32.3 CPython/3.12.4 Linux/6.8.0-45-generic linuxmint/22 glibc/2.39 solver/libmamba conda-libmamba-solver/24.7.0 libmambapy/1.5.8 aau/0.4.4 c/. s/. e/.
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


Problem seems to be linked to 61022248. I installed anaconda like it is described by the user hobs. It's up an running now
